# How to sort a list of objects based on the value of a field

Tags: python

I used to have the following representation of a player:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from pprint import pprint
from typing import Union

@dataclass
class Player:
    name: str
    club: str
    is_captain: bool
    is_vice_captain: bool

players = [
    Player("Desmond Bane",   "MEM", False, False),
    Player("Jaren Jackson",  "MEM", False,  True),
    Player("Steven Adams",   "MEM", False, False),
    Player("Ja Morant",      "MEM", True,  False),
    Player("Dillion Brooks", "MEM", False, False),
    ]
```

Which I could easily sort by captaincy:

```
sorted_players = sorted(players, key=lambda x: (x.is_captain, x.is_vice_captain), reverse=True)
pprint(sorted_players)

[Player(name='Ja Morant', club='MEM', is_captain=True, is_vice_captain=False),
 Player(name='Jaren Jackson', club='MEM', is_captain=False, is_vice_captain=True),
 Player(name='Desmond Bane', club='MEM', is_captain=False, is_vice_captain=False),
 Player(name='Steven Adams', club='MEM', is_captain=False, is_vice_captain=False),
 Player(name='Dillion Brooks', club='MEM', is_captain=False, is_vice_captain=False)]
```

Now I have reduced the captaincy to one field:

```
Captain = 'cap'
Vice_captain = 'vice_cap'
Non_captain = None
Captaincy = Union[Captain, Vice_captain, Non_captain]

@dataclass
class Player2:
    name: str
    club: str
    captaincy: Captaincy

players2 = [
    Player2("Desmond Bane",   "MEM", Non_captain),
    Player2("Jaren Jackson",  "MEM", Vice_captain),
    Player2("Steven Adams",   "MEM", Non_captain),
    Player2("Ja Morant",      "MEM", Captain),
    Player2("Dillion Brooks", "MEM", Non_captain),
    ]
```

Having done this, I'm wondering how can I sort the players so that captain goes first, vice-captain goes second followed by the rest of the team?

Comment: An ``enum`` would be more appropriate than a ``Union`` here, especially as ``Captain`` and ``Vice_captain`` are not types. It is rather easy to make an ``enum`` ordered.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how to sort it with `Enum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `dict` to encode the hierarchy

```py
values = {Captain:1, Vice_captain: 2}
sorted_players = sorted(players2, key=lambda x: values.get(x.captaincy, 3))
```